# WPF databound TextBox cursor position resetting. Possible bug?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, cursor-position

So I'm having this weird problem. I have a TextBox bound to the ViewModel :

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Path=FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

With the content of FilterText, I am filtering a `ListBox` (which is bound to an `ObservableCollection`).

Now everything works fine. But after each keystroke, the cursor position of this `TextBox` keeps resetting to the beginning. And this is happening only with this particular `TextBox`. I have other bound `TextBox` working just fine.

I googled it, and found that this happens in `.NET4.0`. But mainly when there is a string formatting or string to double conversion is involved. But FilterText is simple `String` property and no `double` variable is involved anywhere.

Here is the code :

```
private String _filterText;
public String FilterText
{
    get { return _filterText; }
    set
    {
        if (_filterText != value)
        {
            _filterText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FilterText");
            FilterList(); //this method works fine
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?
The solutions suggested somewhere else includes changing `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus` or using an attached behavior to manually set the cursor location. Is there any other simpler solution? Or is this just a bug?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem does not occur if you commented the call to `FilterList()` in the `FilterText` property setter?

Comment: show us the FilterList code, something there causing the problem

Comment: @blindmeis, here is the code. I have also provided the code for ObservableCollectionEx, used in the method.

http://pastebin.com/1Q69LDRe

Comment: @AritraBhowmick I can reproduce issues like [one you mentioned](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588343/changed-behaviour-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-0-of-wpf-textbox-formatting-when-propertychanged-is-used-as-updatesourcetrigger) However yours just works fine for me. As a wild guess try replacing the call to `FilterList()` with a `RaisePropertyChanged("Questions")` in `FilterText` setter and in the property getter of `Questions` before returning `_questions` add the `FilterList()` method call. Logic should be the same with this and could fix some thread updating issue.

Comment: @Viv, did as you suggested. No luck. Caret position is not correctly updated.
I even added a behavior as suggested [here](http://blog.spencen.com/2010/05/05/preventing-a-bound-textbox-from-resetting-the-caret-position.aspx). But still the same thing.

Comment: @AritraBhowmick yeh soz, don't think I can be of much help unless I can reproduce this but I'm not able to. Maybe try to put a sample together which shows the problem and upload it somewhere and link to your post to help people get the same setup that causes the issue.

Comment: @Viv, [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?82grxp9cahp29n6) is a sample build, with db.

Comment: @AritraBhowmick I meant the code(just minimal amount required to show the error) as a sample sln which when run can show this error not the exe itself.

Comment: @Viv, the problem is really annoying! [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?u0r0xc22q4k332n) is the code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got your source-code and could reproduce the issue. However it wasn't one of those .NET 4 issues cos it had the same issue in .NET 4.5. Actually turns out it's not an issue in .NET at all.

In `ManageQuestionViewModel.cs`

switch

```
public void Initialize() {
...
  this.ViewCore.FocusQuestionData();
}
```

to

```
public void Initialize() {
...
  // this.ViewCore.FocusQuestionData();
}
```

you're done :)

oh and you do not need that `ResetCaretBehavior` you've added to try and work-around this anymore as well

Comment: Huh. Never even thought about that! Thnx.